# Swap memory problems

Tags: partitioning

I deleted my 16 gigabytes swap memory and now it is unallocated space.

How can I join that space with the other 484 gigabytes?

Screenshot :

[image: Imgur]

BTW I cannot shutdown after removing that memory.

What are the logs I can look at to see what's going on ?

Comment: When you were removing the swap space, did you first "swapoff" the memory before deleting the partition? You can use gparted to swapoff (or terminal: sudo swapoff --all). This should properly dismount the swap space and let you shutdown and or reallocate the freed space

Comment: @amc No. I just removed the swap space using gnome-disks.How long will `sudo swapoff --all` take?

Comment: it should be very quick (a few seconds tops). I'm not sure if you'll run into problems with already having removed the partition though.

Comment: @amc It starts and does not stop. system-monitor says `Swap - Not available` and Gparted scans for devices for minutes.

Comment: yeah likely a problem with having deleted the partition. is the swap listed in /etc/fstab? (terminal: cat /etc/fstab)

Comment: `# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=fe51b148-f867-4c14-aec2-f304d0b41d7d none            swap    sw              0       0
` Does that help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7635/discussion-between-aleksandar-and-amc)

Answer (score 0):

for merge the partitions you can use partitions manager , if windows is there then right click on "My computer " -> select "Manage" -> in "Storage" -> "disk management" , here you can merge your partitions.

for booting use Easybcd software it is free for home user and install it. open it you will see add new entry click on it go to linux tab add entry click and selcet "swap partition" and "GRUB2" in it after that click on edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting.

Download here:http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

Comment: I do not have windows. Only Ubuntu 12.10.